# Execute BigQuery using python sdk from Jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, google-bigquery, gcloud

I have a python program executing bigquery using cloud service account successfully.
When I try to schedule the python program using Jenkins, I see the below error
The gcloud user has bigquery editor, dataowner and admin permission to table, and dataset.

**Log:**
gcloud auth activate-service-account abc --key-file=****
Activated service account credentials for: abc273721.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
gcloud config set project p1
Updated property p1.
**403 Access Denied: Table XYZ: User does not have permission to query table**

Comment: Double check the service account has the correct IAM first. Also, is the query that it's running trying to access a table in another project by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have provided all the required roles; bigquery.dataOwner & bigquery.admin,as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#required_permissions) but it looks like you have to also grant the [service account access to the dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Create a service account with `BigQuery Admin Role` and download JSON key file (`example`: data-lab.json).
Use below code:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account "service-account" --key-file=data-lab.json --project="project-name"
```